# Difference between oracle current logons count and sessions utilization

Tags: oracle

below query we can get get current logons count:

```
 SELECT VALUE AS current_logon_count FROM v$sysstat WHERE name = 'logons current';
```

also below query will return current sessions utilization :

```
SELECT resource_name,
       current_utilization  current_count     
  FROM v$resource_limit
WHERE resource_name IN ('sessions');
```

what is the difference between current logons count and current sessions utilization?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Updated]**
Sorry, my conclusion was too hasty after checking of oracle docs.
Now, I've tested these parameters on an oracle instance, and indeed, `current_utilization:sessions` does not show the maximum number of logons during the instance run time.

What it shows is well explained [here](http://tech.e2sn.com/oracle/oracle-internals-and-architecture/recursive-sessions-and-ora-00018-maximum-number-of-sessions-exceeded).

**In short**:
`v$sysstat` "current logons" show current number of sessions in `v$session`.
And according to the link above, `v$session` holds only *USER* and *BACKGROUND* sessions.

There is another type of session: *RECURSIVE*.
`v$resource_limit`'s `current_utilization:session` reflects all three types of sessions, so in most cases, these numbers are going to be different.

So, both parameters count the sessions currently in the instance, but they do it differently.

**[Initial answer]**
According to the [description of v$sysstat metrics](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B16240_01/doc/doc.102/e16282/oracle_database_help/oracle_database_database_resource_usage_logons.html) current logons:

> This metric represents the current number of logons.

And according to the [description of v$resource_limit](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/dynviews_2128.htm#REFRN30206), and [further](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/dynviews_2128.htm#REFRN30206)

> SESSIONS specifies the maximum number of sessions that can be created in the system.

So, the difference is between the current and the maximum number of users.

Comment: Hi , but i am selecting the "CURRENT_UTILIZATION" field it says
"CURRENT_UTILIZATION NUMBER Number of (resources, locks, or processes) currently being used"
not the maximum no

Comment: @TAB, sorry for misleading information, I've updated my answer.